# Profile picture uploads - Client side or server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, client-server, user-experience

***Building a  upload profile picture system.***

Looking for a system to allow square images and allow user to select small part of large image (means need cropping). Also validate based on size and dimensions as per needs.

**Client side cropping**

HTML5 canvas and localstorage based solutions are present like ngImgCrop, Angular Image Crop, but there are problems like -

- image distorts if high resultion (more than 1 MB)
- may be not supported in some old (non-html5) browsers

**Server side cropping**

Solutions like Jcrop but long workflow and time/bandwidth consuming.

- client needs to send full large file to server even if its 5MB
- then download it again from server to preview
- then show crop UI and send crop co-ordinates
- server performs cropping and creates file
- cropped image is downloaded and displayed

What will be the best approach. Tell me more pros and cons of each. What should a great startup do and what is the industry standard solution as of now and why?

Answer (score 2):

The best answer to this mainly depends on your target audience. Many people who are used to using online services will have a pre-cropped or small version of their profile image ready to upload, and will know not to try to upload a 20 mega-pixel photo. If your target audience is more traditional, then you will probably want to shift your approach to be more forgiving and focussed on older, widely supported technologies.

For me, the best solution is the following:

- Focus on a client-side solution - have the user crop the photo on the client side, then optimise it on the server.
- To counter the massive photo image, either have a simple label "max file size: 1mb", or check the file size when they initially select the photo, and upload & resize/compress it first.

> What should a great startup do and what is the industry standard solution as of now and why?

A great startup should not be restricted or over-influenced by industry standards and should reason through the various approaches themselves.